# I have a site with a button which should be centered but for some reason it isnt

Tags: html, css

I just started with html about four days ago and me and my friend are trying to make a site to put all the scripts we make in and the button goes back to the main site, i have it on two more sites but the button really just doesn't want to cooperate on this one. we've been trying to figure it out for the past day or two but no matter what we try it just keeps sticking to the right side.

```css
body {
      font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
      background-color: black;
    }
    
    h1 {
      color: lightgray;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
    }
    
    p {
      color: lightgrey;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
    }
    
    .button {
      border-radius: 8px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      background-color: #ad0000;
      border: outset #ad0000;
      color: darkgrey;
      padding: 15px 30px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
      float: none;
      clear: both;
    }
    
    .button:hover {
      background-color: red;
      color: darkgray;
      border: inset #ad0000;
    }
    
    div#gallery {
      margin-bottom: 100px;
    }
    
    div.gallery {
      margin: 5px;
      border: 8px outset #2a2a2a;
      float: left;
      width: 180px;
    }
    
    div.gallery img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    div.desc {
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: center;
      color: lightgray;
      background: #2a2a2a;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    
      <h1>About us</h1>
    
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="deepfry.doey.png">
          <img src="deepfry.doey.png" alt="Doey">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">description</div>
      </div>
    
    <p>
      <a href="grandarchive 2.html" class="button">Back to the Archive</a>
    </p>
```

Comment: Try editing this post to use a "code snippet" so we can easily see the result of your code.

Comment: You want the button centered with the heading?

Comment: @EternalHour i want it centered at the bottom of the page wherever that may be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand that `HTML` have hierarchies, so child element style can't affect parent element sibling. so the fix is to move the `clear:both` from the `a` tag(chilg) to `p` tag(parent).

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
  background-color: black;
}

h1 {
  color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
}

p {
  color: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
  clear: both;
}

.button {
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #ad0000;
  border: outset #ad0000;
  color: darkgrey;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: none;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: darkgray;
  border: inset #ad0000;
}

div#gallery {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

div.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 8px outset #2a2a2a;
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: lightgray;
  background: #2a2a2a;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>

  <h1>About us</h1>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="deepfry.doey.png">
      <img src="deepfry.doey.png" alt="Doey">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Im doey and I just started writing python here in the grand year of 2020, when my friend Banj showed it to me. I also played a major role in putting together this site!</div>
  </div>

<p>
  <a href="grandarchive 2.html" class="button">Back to the Archive</a>
</p>
```